# Ajax Request to Spring Boot Endpoint Failed to Read HTTP MSG

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I have an ajax request passing data to a spring boot endpoint. However I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public java.lang.String com.applicationName.controller.EventController.deleteCalendarEvents(com.applicationName.model.Vacation,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
```

Here's my Ajax Request:

```
$.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/vacation/deleteEvents',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(vacation),
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response !== "OK")
                            alert(response);
                        else
                            console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                });
```

And here's my Spring Boot endpoint:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/vacation/deleteEvents", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteCalendarEvents (@RequestBody Vacation vacation, HttpSession session){
    //code
}
```

If I change this to a POST it gives me an error saying I can't post to a GET and reading online people were suggesting to change to a GET. If you have any suggestions please let me know. I have a feeling i'm missing a core concept here. Thanks. I will try any suggestions and post updates.

Comment: `RequestMethod.GET` endpoints cannot have `@RequestBody` also you are using `POST` in you front-end so use `RequestMethod.POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are trying to POST something to someone that is ready to accept GET. It's like talking english to a person speaking only italian... They can't understant each other.

Whatever your reasons are, you must make your client and server speaking the same language, and using the same tunnel... If your client POST, your server must accept POST. If your client GET, your server must accept GET.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/vacation/deleteEvents',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(vacation),
    success: function (response) {
        if (response !== "OK")
            alert(response);
        else
            console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});

@RequestMapping(value = "/vacation/deleteEvents", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteCalendarEvents (@RequestBody Vacation vacation, HttpSession session){
    //code
}
```

If you want to accept GET, then your client must send a GET request:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/vacation/deleteEvents',
    success: function (response) {
        if (response !== "OK")
            alert(response);
        else
            console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});

@RequestMapping(value = "/vacation/deleteEvents", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String deleteCalendarEvents (HttpSession session){
    //code
}
```

So, you have to POST if you want to be able to retrieve the `@RequestBody`.

But then, in a more RESTFul oriented way, you could send a DELETE request:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: `/vacation/${vacation.id}`, // assuming your object vacation has an id field.
    success: function (response) {
        if (response !== "OK")
            alert(response);
        else
            console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});

@RequestMapping(value = "/vacation/{vacationId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public String deleteCalendarEvents (@PathVariable int vacationId, HttpSession session){
    //code
}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: when I change both the Ajax 'method' to POST and change the spring boot endpoint to 'RequestMethod.GET' I get the following error: Request method 'GET' not supported. To be clear, i'm trying to SEND data from the ajax request to the spring boot end point. I'm not trying to send data FROM the spring boot endpoint. Thanks for your response

Comment: Try having both ajax sending POST and spring boot listening POST. Don't mix them.

Comment: Fantastic, worked like a charm. Had an underlying issue that had to due with bad characters with the request, but once I got that cleared up it worked great. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/vacation/deleteEvents", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String deleteCalendarEvents (@RequestBody Vacation vacation){
    //code
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of just posting code add some explanation what the code does.